# how to use rails databases? guide?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am having some trouble understanding how to use databases with ruby on rails. I know that my app works fine when i generate a scaffold and add/edit models. What i do not understand is if anything changes when i put my rails app online, does it still use the .sqlite3 file in the db folder? or do i connect it to my sites SQL server?

If you do switch and connect to a SQL server why is this?

Is there a guide or tutorial on this topic that you can point me to perhaps? my searching mostly came up with migrating tutorials. I just want to figure out how Rails works when it is live on a website.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SQLite on production with no problems, although it is not the ideal option.

On production is more recommendable to use a more powerful solution. You can see at the official guide how to switch: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#configuring-a-database

Comment: so if i configure it to us mySQL that comes with my hosting package and then run $ rake db:create and then db:migrate it will create the tables and everything that I have been using in my sqlite DB?

Comment: Yes, that's the advantage of using an ORM.

Comment: ok cool thank you. Im loving rails so far and was just having a hard time getting my head around this part. Thanks for the help1